# How to renew a client DHCP address with an OpenWrt router?

Tags: router, dhcp, ip-address, openwrt

How to renew a client DHCP address with an OpenWrt router, from its SSH terminal session?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Done the research and answering to the future me. OpenWrt uses `udhcpc` as its DHCP client (rather than `dhclient`). To renew DHCP leases on all interfaces, the following one-liner can be used (thanks to [the source](https://gergap.wordpress.com/2008/08/13/howto-renew-a-dhcp-lease/)):

```
PID=`pidof udhcpc` && kill -SIGUSR1 $PID
```